# android unfortunately has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am new at android.This code is not giving any error when i compile it but i load it in avd its giving "Android unfortunately has stopped" error.What i am doing wrong.Thanks for everything

```
package com.exampldse.aaasdasd;


import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    TextView cikti=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button tus =(Button)  findViewById(R.id.button1);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cikti.setText("dasda");

            }
        });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to this. You are trying to get button with id before you call its container layout

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView cikti;
    Button tus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cikti=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tus =(Button)  findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cikti.setText("dasda");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ne demek bişey değil :)

Comment: :D eyw kardeşim ismail i şimdi gördüm:D

Answer (score 0):

you can this code for your mainActivity.java file

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```